# Read char array, one char at a time

Tags: java, arrays

My program saves user input as a string (UI), then splits it into an array 
`char[] charArray = UI.toCharArray();` After this the program needs to read the first letter in `charArray`, use it for different part of the program, and then proceed to the next letter in the array. The problem is reading the array one letter at a time.

How do you access each character in an array in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)
{
   char UIChar = charArray[i];
   // Do something with your character in the string.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to loop the array:

```
for (char ch : charArray) {
   // do something with letter ch
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce your work, you don't even need the char array.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < UI.length() ; i++) {
    char c = UI.charAt(i);
    // Your remaining code
}
```